# Why am I getting these two errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Before you post comments about it, I am POSITIVE that my files are in the correct positions.

### Here is my first error:

I have Bootstrap, Font Awesome, and jQuery in my web page.

I am getting an error that reads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
at bootstrap-4.3.1.min.js:6
at bootstrap-4.3.1.min.js:6                                  bootstrap-4.3.1.min.js:6
at bootstrap-4.3.1.min.js:6
```

I know there are other questions like this, but they do not solve my problems.

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51369979/bootstrap-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-fn-of-undefined), some of the answers are telling me to make a script tag and do this:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery'); // not sure if you need this at all
window.Bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
```

This does not work for me.

How do I stop this error from persisting?

### My second error:

For some reason, one of my files is calling `fa-solid-900.woff`,
`fa-solid-900.woff2`, and`fa-solid-900.ttf`.

nowhere in my code did I call these files, yet I get an error saying

```
GET file:///C:/Users/temporarily-me/OneDrive/Desktop/Web/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
GET file:///C:/Users/temporarily-me/OneDrive/Desktop/Web/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
GET file:///C:/Users/temporarily-me/OneDrive/Desktop/Web/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I do not have a `webfonts` folder, much less the files it is calling, and I cannot find where it is calling them.

If it helps, I am using Chrome, jQuery.min.js 3.4.1, Bootstrap.min.js 4.3.1, Bootstrap.min.css 4.3.1, and font-awesome.min.css 5.8.2.

Here is my code for both errors:

```js
var $fixme   = $( '.fixme' );
var fixmeTop = $fixme.offset().top;
var $main    = $( 'main' );
var $win     = $( window );

$win.scroll( function () {

  var atSticky = $win.scrollTop() >= fixmeTop;
  
  $fixme.toggleClass( 'sticky', atSticky );
  $main.css( 'padding-top', atSticky ? fixmeTop + 5 : 0 );
  
} );

$(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
    var $nav = $(".fixme");
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
  });
});
```

```css
.fixme {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  color: red;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.a {
 height: 60px;
 background-color: green;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: 0 solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}

ul,
ol {
  margin: 0;
}

ul li,
ol li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title> Web Page </title>

        <!-- these are just here since Stack Overflow does not have the latest libraries, so I used them ;) -->    
    
        <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-------------------->

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/font-awesome-5.8.2.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/bootstrap-4.3.1.min.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <header>
   <div class="top-header-area">
   
    <p style="float: left; font-size: 32px;">Logo Here</p>
   
    <div class="search-login-area">
    
     <div class="search-area">
     
      <form action="#" method="post">
      
       <input type="search" name="top-search" id="topSearch" placeholder="Search">
       
       <button type="submit" class="btn">
       
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        
       </button>
       
      </form>
     </div>
    
     <div class="login-area">
     
      <a href="#">
      
       <span>Login / Register</span>
       
       <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       
      </a>
      
     </div>
     
    </div>
    
   </div>
   
   <div class="fixme">
   
    <div id="stickynav" class="stickynav">Sticky Div is very Sticky.
    
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
  <main>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
  </main>
  
  
  <script src="Javascript/Bootstrap/bootstrap-4.3.1.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="Javascript/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="Javascript/Active.js" ></script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Load the scripts **inside** `<head>` and you are calling jQuery 2 times... fix that

Comment: also the `fa-` errors  are because you are calling a fontawesome css file but don't have the webfonts

Comment: Do I have to use the webfonts to stop the errors? and @Roy, where am I calling jQuery twice? If you mean the `<link>` tags above the `<!DOCTYPE html>`, those are libraries outside of Stack Overflow since they do not have the latest versions.

Comment: @Temporarilyme beginning of the file and before `</body>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is my first error:**

Change Order, First load jquery file then bootstrap file

```
<script src="Javascript/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" ></script>
<script src="Javascript/Bootstrap/bootstrap-4.3.1.min.js" ></script>
```